# alinhar imagem ao centro sobre outra imagem

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap

estou desenvolvendo um site como portifolio, estou usando wordpress e bootstrap, criei uma div e dentro desta coloquei uma tag img com a imagem de fundo dessa div, porem agora quero colocar uma imagem do meu logo sobreposta ao background, usando algumas propriedades do css ate consigo colocar ela sobreposta porem nao consigo alinha-la ao centro

meu codigo esta assim:

```
<div class="img-fundo">
    <img class="img-logo" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/images/logo.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img-fundo img-responsive" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/images/header.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

css esta assim:

```
.img-fundo{
    display: block;
}

.img-logo{
    position: absolute;
    magin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

ela sobrepoe mas nao alinha ao centro. como devo proceder?

Comment: Pra imagem alinhar ao centro tem que da um width a classe .img-logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma das maneiras de centralizar um elemento com CSS, com a posição absoluta, usa-se o `left` com 50% e `margin-left` com metade negativa da largura do elemento, isso garante que sempre estará no centro.

Para alinhar a logo ao centro descubra a largura `width` desta imagem e altere a classe no CSS para algo desse tipo:

```
.img-logo{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    magin-left: -50px; //-50px se a logo tiver largura de 100px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou colocar uma div dentro da "img-fundo" e nela você por a imagem do seu logo? Creio que poderia dar certo, usando o CSS para centralizá-la e até mesmo uma class.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso usando jquery:

```
    <div class="img-fundo">
        <img id ="imgFundo" class="img-fundo img-responsive" src="..." alt="">
        <img id ="imgLogo" class="img-logo" src="..." alt="">

    <script>
        var fundo = $( "#imgFundo" );
        var logo = $( "#imgLogo" );

        logo.css("padding-top", fundo.height()/2 - logo.height()/2);
        logo.css("padding-left", fundo.width()/2 - logo.width()/2);
    </script>
</div>
```